# Can lyrics be read on Podcasts?

Tags: copyright

I have a podcast where I am reviewing and telling the story about old hymns, Christian music, and artist.  It is about trying to save the older songs and listening to the older artist.  A lot of the music I am talking about is in the public domain so there is not a problem but some are writers and artist from the 50s to the 80s.  I am trying to spotlight the great words and music we had back then.  Can I read the lyrics to the songs without infringing on the copyright laws?  This podcast is mostly a review of the songs.

Answer (score 2):

### Maybe

Let's skip over the obvious: if you get permission from the copyright owner, no problem.

If you do not get permission, then probably no.

There may be jurisdictions, like the USA, where you can claim [fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) as a defence to copyright infringement. It's not completely clear what you are doing and if this use would meet the criteria, but it sounds like it might.

But you're making a podcast, which means it will be available everywhere, or at least everywhere that speaks English. In those jurisdictions, you have a [fair dealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_dealing) defence, but complete copying is *never* fair dealing. If you read only extracts and only so much as you need for your "reviewing and telling the story" then you might be fair dealing and, incidentally, this will strengthen your fair use defence.